# How can I query rsyslog settings?

Tags: configuration, syslog

I am using rsyslog for program logging and system logging so I have unified log files. I'm having some messages dropping out and I'm not sure why, but I think it may be a configuration option set incorrectly or left at a default value I need to change. I know I can set the values for options in rsyslog.conf but how can I see what is being used by rsyslog currently?

I have searched for a while for the answer to this online and can't believe it's not possible, someone must have needed this and figured it out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps you could attach your configuration so people can review it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option for querying rsyslog config, see the [rsyslogd(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rsyslogd.8.html) man page and that's why you can't find anything.

If you want to [check rsyslog config](http://www.rsyslog.com/how-can-i-check-the-config/), you may use the following command:

```
rsyslogd -N1
```

> This tells rsyslog to do a config check. It does NOT run in regular
>   mode, but just check configuration file correctness. This option is
>   meant to verify a config file. To do so, run rsyslogd interactively in
>   foreground, specifying -f  and -N level. The level
>   argument modifies behaviour. Currently, 0 is the same as not
>   specifying the -N option at all (so this makes limited sense) and 1
>   actually activates the code.

See deatils here: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/troubleshooting/troubleshoot.html#configuration-problems

Or you can use debugging, here is [How to use debug on demand](http://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-debug-on-demand/)